How to split an array of objects into chunks based on max memory size of each chunk(say in bytes) in JavaScript?
I have an array of objects in JavaScript, and I need to split this array into smaller chunks where each chunk's total size does not exceed a specified byte limit.
Each object can have varying sizes, and I want to use the byte size of each object (after stringifying it) as the basis for chunking. I am using Node.js and want to ensure I account for the size correctly, using Buffer.byteLength.
How can I achieve this in JavaScript?
Here’s an example of what I want to do:
const data = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Alice' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Bob' },
  // potentially many more objects
];

const maxSizeInBytes = 100; // Example size limit for each chunk


What is the best way to chunk an array of objects by their memory size in JavaScript?

If you need to split an array of objects into smaller chunks based on their byte size, you can achieve this by calculating the byte size of each object using Buffer.byteLength after converting the object to a JSON string.
Here’s a function that will split the array into smaller arrays, ensuring that the total size of objects in each chunk doesn't exceed the specified size limit:
function chunkByBytes<T>(arr: T[], size: number): T[][] {
  const chunks = [];
  let chunkSize = 0;
  let chunk = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
    const item = arr[index];
    const itemSize = Buffer.byteLength(JSON.stringify(item)); // Get byte size of the item
    
    // If adding this item exceeds the max size, start a new chunk
    if (chunkSize + itemSize > size) {
      chunks.push(chunk);
      chunkSize = 0;
      chunk = [];
    }
    
    // Add the item to the current chunk
    chunk.push(item);
    chunkSize += itemSize;
  }

  // Add the last chunk if not empty
  if (chunk.length > 0) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  }

  return chunks;
}

const data = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Alice' },
  { id: 2, name: 'Bob' },
  { id: 3, name: 'Charlie' }
];
// usage
const maxSizeInBytes = 50;
const result = chunkByBytes(data, maxSizeInBytes);

console.log(result);



For each object, we calculate the byte size using Buffer.byteLength(JSON.stringify(item)). This gives the byte size of the object after it's been serialized to a JSON string.

How is it exceeding @James? can you elaborate please?

Sorry I thought chunk was the current item instead of item.
